# I cannot get rid of hyper V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

So today I tried to emulate a game on gameloop however it said I have hyper v installed and its incompatible, I was confused because I have windows 11 home version therefore it should not have hyper V. I checked task manager virtualization was on I opened BIOS and it had no hyper V settings. so I ran systeminfo on cmds and it says "a hypervisor has been detected. Features required  for Hyper - V will not be displayed. whenever I tried to remove it using power shell it would say that it doesn't recognize the feature ( meaning it somehow doesnt exist ) even though my system says it does and so does gameloop, I have tried looking troubleshooting this for hours updated my windows version installed Restoro to no avail. if anyone can help I would appreciate it

Comment: Did you check Windows Features to see if Hyper-V was there?

Comment: [Edit[ your question and include a screenshot of what Windows features you do have installed. Windows 11 Home CANNOT enable Hyper-V, so the message is suggesting something else and/or that Gameloop error message is thrown for multiple reasons.  **Hyper-V is a feature of Windows not your device's firmware.** Hyper-V is a hypervisor which requires hardware virtualization to be enabled to use, VT-X  or AMD-V, is the hardware virtualization extension to the x86/x64 architecture. You should also give us the **exact** error message.

Comment: @Ramhound FYI, it is possible to install Hyper-V on Windows 11 Home with a simple hack

Comment: @Keltari - The author hasn't implemented that hack. I have my theory on the author's problem, I am waiting no more information from the author themselves, before I submit an answer.

Comment: "A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed" can be displayed for other Windows features, like WSL2, etc.  It can be a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

- In Windows *Services* Control Panel

  - Double-click (or presss <kbd>Enter</kbd>) for each *Hyper-V* item.
  - If running, clicj *Stop*.
  - Set *Startup type:* to *Disabled*.

[image: Stop HyperVisor Services]

- You might also turn off virtualization in BIOS, is available.

If you decide at a later time to use virtualization, just reverse these steps. If you need to switch frequently, export all the Hyper-V keys in each state(e.g., `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HvHost`) , auto and disabled, and combine into two .reg files, one to *enable* Hyper-V, the other to *disable*.

See [Black Viper’s Windows 10 Service Configurations](https://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/) for more info.